# Jenkins P4 Plugin: How to perform Jenkins variable expansion on a Perforce client template?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, perforce

I am currently working on configuring a Jenkins build system, but I've run into some issues with p4jenkins' client spec configuration. I currently have a cluster of four machines (a master and 3 agents), each with two executors each. I know each executor needs to have a unique workspace, but I'd also prefer to not need to manually define workspaces in-line in the Jenkinsfile. Part of the trouble is these jobs are run across different branches, and for compatibility reasons, I cannot use a Jenkins multi-branch pipeline (though to be perfectly honest I don't believe that would solve this problem anyway.)

Easy enough to fix, though, right? Our depot follows the pattern of `//depot/$BRANCH/...`, and [in the P4 Plugin documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/p4-plugin/blob/master/docs/VARIABLEEXPANSION.md) it says that I should be able to embed variables in-line to a mapping and they will expand when the job is run, so I create a template containing mappings along the line of:
`//depot/${BRANCH}/... //jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}-${EXECUTOR_NUMBER}/${BRANCH}/...` (The broadness is for sake of example; the actual jobs only map a subsection of each branch.), and include a Jenkins axis with the name BRANCH and the values of the branches in question.

However, when I try to run my job with this template, the variable expands to an empty string, though the other job- or executor-specific variables appear to expand correctly. Additionally, running the job on a single branch with a client specification file read from the depot also does not work.

The above mapping *does* work when defined in a manual workspace, but as I stated above, I would prefer to avoid that if possible as it's a maintenance nightmare.

In the documentation, it's mentioned that mappings need to be surrounded with single-quotes (`'`) or triple-single-quotes (`'''`) for the expansion to work correctly, but that doesn't seem to be compatible with Jenkins templates or specs. Further, the page also mentions "Using full double quotes expands the variables early and the script will fail.", which is directly opposite my experience, where it doesn't expand properly using single-quotes but does with double-quotes in the in-line Custom Workspace definition in the Jenkinsfile proper.

My question is this: How does one get Jenkins variable expansion to work with Perforce client templates?

We're using Perforce Server 2017.1 and Jenkins 2.263.1 (which I believe, at time of posting, is the latest version.)

Thank you for your time and any help is much appreciated!